# Can a risky asset have negative beta coefficient?

Tags: accounting, risk, risk-management, beta

I have a question from my tutorial asking whether

Can a risky asset have negative beta coefficient?

I can only think of how this is possible only if risk-free rate is more than the expected returns, are there any other reasons for such?

Comment: Does a short contract count as an asset?

Comment: I don't know the rules but I'd say yes.  It would seem to me that a put and a call would be also apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative beta means that the security moves in the opposite direction of the  index that it's being compared to.

Comment: In what applications can this be applied? (other than diversification?)

Comment: I don't know other than as a hedge.